# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Error when POST, JSON data to Bitnami Redmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, localhost, redmine, redmine-api

I am trying to build a rest client to POST data to Redmine API. I don't think i could change anything on Redmine(sever side) API. to give access. I have installed Redmine bitnami stack locally(Redmine -> localhost/redmine).
And client side files are on localhost:8080

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").on('click', function(){
            // send ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/redmine/projects.json', 
                type : "post", 
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType : 'json',
                headers: { 'X-Redmine-API-Key': 'admin' }, 
                data : JSON.stringify({
                          "project": {
                            "name": "MANOJ",
                            "identifier": "MANOJ-perera",
                             "description": "This is a des"
    
  }
}), 
                success : function(result) {
                  
                    alert("Sucess");
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

I am getting following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/redmine/projects/11n. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

How do i solve this issue. Please help.

Comment: you probably need to set up CORS on `http://localhost/`

Comment: I am quite new to this, how do i do that!

Comment: Possibly something to do with the `Redmine bitnami stack` - hang around, someone may have a complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by bringing both hosts to a common platform without changing anything on severside.
Copied all the data in localhost:8080 to localhost. In my case Redmine bitnami stack was in localhost and web application i develop was in localhost:8080 brought all the webapp files to C:\Bitnami\redmine\apache2\htdocs\ and it solved.